# Does this feature exist in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw bar to pie chart with Highcharts like this 
[image: bar to pie]
is it possible !?

Comment: You can use two series: pie / bar and missing lines add by renderer http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path

Comment: Oh, this would be fun to implement!